# How to read `v.s.` for two players?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes for a match, there are two players, and in the screen, it shows `Player1 v.s. Player2`.

My question is how to read this to others?

1. Player one v dot s dot Player two
2. Player one v s Player two
3. Player one versus Player two

Which is right? And which is most people using?

Comment: I'd go for option 3.

Comment: Two dots...not aware of! It's okay **without dot** as well! Freewind vs Boundwind! It's okay **without 's'** also! Freewind v FreeWater! ;)

Comment: @MaulikV FreeWater +1 :)

Comment: **A v.s. B** is old style abbreviation when screen real estate was less important, **A v B** is BrE style, **A vs B** is AmE style, **A versus B** is spelled out and always correct but takes up a lot of space. As an aside: in BrE the **home team** is listed first, in AmE the **home team** is listed second

Comment: @Peter Interesting information about the teams. I'm American and didn't know there was a fixed order, but then again I know nothing about sports. Is it common across all sports?

Comment: The ordering is common across all sports, it's very obvious the first time watching results on the tele, I think it's because the British have an underlying belief in **precedence**, but I always thought the US way was more **courteous** in that one mentions oneself last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you can go about this:

In a *formal setting*, or you want to ensure that you are understood, use ***versus***:

- Arsenal *versus* Tottenham

In a more causal setting, or if you are with someone well-versed in either sports in general, or the situation in particular, you can use the letter ***v***:

- Arsenal *v* Tottenham

But in a general setting, when everyone knows each other, you can ***skip it*** altogether:

- Arsenal, Tottenham.

As an aside: What I found confusing when I first got into sports, is that in America, the *Home Team* is on the *Right Side* of the One-vs-Two equation. But in Europe (not sure about Asia) the *Home Team* is on the Left Side of One-vs-Two.

Comment: Actually, "versus" is usually abbreviated as "vs." or "v.," depending on mostly preference. Though it is a convention to write court case names with a "v." (example: Korematsu v. United States)

Answer (score 4):

Your option third is the most commonly used version. In my opinion, that is the correct way to read it too.

> Player one versus Player two

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/versus) defines *"versus"* as : *'used to say that one ​team or ​person is ​competing against another'* . Even though it is abbreviated as *'vs'*, it should be read out as "versus".